# How to filter an object with ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm building a view where I add a product to a cart. To do this I create an instance of a CartItem model which is related to a cart, a product and has variations (color, size...).

When the instance of CartItem is created I want to check if it already exists to know if I need to increment its stock or create a new one. So I first check for one with the same cart and product (ok so far). But then I don't know how to check if one that has the same variations exists (which is a ManytoMany field).

the view:

```
def add_to_cart(request, product_id):

    product = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)
    variation_list = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        for item in request.POST:
            key = item
            value = request.POST[key]
            try: 
                variation = Variation.objects.get(product = product, variation_category__iexact = key, variation_value__iexact = value)
                variation_list.append(variation)
            except:
                pass
        print(variation_list)

    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_get_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id=_get_cart_id(request))
        cart.save()
        
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product,cart=cart)

        # How to filter cart_item so I know if it matches with variation_list

        cart_item.product_quantity +=1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(product=product,cart=cart)
        cart_item.save()
        for variation in variation_list:
            cart_item.variation_list.add(variation)
    return redirect('cart')
```

the Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/products')
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse("product_slug", args=[self.category.slug,self.slug])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

the Variation model:

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation_category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=variation_category_choices)
    variation_value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product.name} {self.variation_category} {self.variation_value}'
```

and the CartItem model:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart= models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    variation_list = models.ManyToManyField(Variation, blank=True)

    def str(self):
        return self.product.name 


    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.product_quantity * self.product.price
```

Thanks!

I tried to somehow loop trough CartItem__variation_list and compare it to the variation_list from the request.POST but obviously it didn't work...

Comment: Instead of checking if a variation of a item already exists in order to sum to its total quantity, you could just keep creating new items without checking if it exists, because it does not matter for the back end. The process of summing the same variations could happen only at the front end, so the user can see a summary of the items in the cart.

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka, thanks for you answer. Mmmh maybe, I'll look this way. But no idea for the ManytoMany filter? I'm really curious to know how it works!